# Floating-point data type for highest performance in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, types, floating-point

I want to use floating-point numbers in my J2ME (MIDP 2.0) program.
I don't need high precision, so I'm considering choosing `float` type.

However, it seems to me that I read a Java article which says that `double` is better supported by processors, so it is faster.

I'm doing many operations with such numbers, so performance is important to me.

The question is, which one of these data types works faster *in J2ME*?

Comment: As is the rule for all performance questions: Measure it. For instance, you could write your program with float, measure its performance (on the target plattform, obviously), do a serach&replace to double, measure performance again, and compare.

Comment: Well, this is J2ME, everything can happen... In the emulator `double` may be better, but on actual mobile phones `float` can win.

Comment: That is why you would measure on the target device :-)

Comment: I've worked on applications, including games, actually deployed on countless different J2ME (JME) devices.  You think you need floating-point numbers but you probably really don't.  What you think needs to be solved using floating-point numbers very probably can be solved using *"integer math"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance difference between float and double is not that significant.

If you are doing those operation very frequently than float is better also it consume less space.

**Update:**

```
 public long sumDouble(){

        double[] arr = new double[1000];
        for(int i = 0 ;i < 1000;i++){
            arr[i]=new Random().nextFloat();
        }
        float sum = 0.0f;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0 ;i < 1000;i++){
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(""+sum);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return end - start;
    }
    public long sumFloat(){

        double[] arr = new double[1000];
        for(int i = 0 ;i < 1000;i++){
            arr[i]=new Random().nextDouble();
        }
        double sum = 0.0f;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int i = 0 ;i < 1000;i++){
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        System.out.println(""+sum);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return end - start;
    }
```

Try executing these methods in your real device to measure the performance difference Its not much significant.

Comment: Do you have any proof of this?